# Dependency tracking in C++: List of all objects dependent on a single object

Tags: list, boost, shared-ptr, ownership

I need to develop a library where I need to track list of objects dependent on another object. Boost library provides some features like `shared_ptr` and `intrusive_ptr` which allow us to track dependencies but they don't give us details like list of all the other objects pointing to a dependent object.

Suppose we have

```
Object B is dependent on A
Object C is dependent on A
(Multiple objects dependent on A)
```

I need some interface like

```
//Adding dependencies
B.dep_obj = A obj
C.dep_obj = A obj
```

After the above operations A should have refcount of 2 (plus a list containing B and C).

```
//Removing dependencies
B.dep_obj = NULL
```

One challenge I see if I opt for overloading `operator=` is to get reference of object B/C since the `operator=` will be part of class representing dep_obj object (and Not class representing B or C). Hence I won't be able to fetch object representing A and B using dep_obj (in generic way)

Comment: What is wrong with `ClassB::dep_obj` simply storing a pointer (possibly `NULL`) to `A_obj`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? C++ has no reflection capability builtin. Also, no garbage collection. Are you trying to add this?